# Multiple buttons appearing on my list (Android Studio to do list app)

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to make a to-do list app using android studio. The intention is an 'add new task' button at the top which opens a dialog through which I can enter a new task. The task then appears in the list below the button.

The issue is that the button keeps appearing after every task on the list (the duplicate buttons are unclickable)

[screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzIqe.png)

Here is my code:

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity {
    // Declare variables

    Button button;
    private TaskDbHelper mHelper;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private ListView mTaskListView;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        // Locate the button in activity_main.xml
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NewTaskButton);
        mHelper = new TaskDbHelper(this);
        mTaskListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        updateUI();
        NewMethod();
    }



    public void NewMethod() {
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final EditText taskEditText = new EditText(ListActivity.this);
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Add a new item");
                alertDialog.setMessage("What item would you like to add?");
                alertDialog.setView(taskEditText);
                alertDialog.setButton("Add item", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // here you can add functions
                        String task = String.valueOf(taskEditText.getText());
                        SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE, task);
                        db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
                                null,
                                values,
                                SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
                        db.close();
                        updateUI();
                    }
                });


                alertDialog.show();  

            }

        });
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
                new String[]{TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID, TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE},
                null, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE);
            taskList.add(cursor.getString(idx));
        }

        if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    R.layout.activity_list,
                    R.id.task_title,
                    taskList);
            mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            mAdapter.clear();
            mAdapter.addAll(taskList);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:divider="#C2AF00"
        android:dividerHeight="3sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/task_title"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/task_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/NewTaskButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/NewTaskButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:text="@string/NewTaskButton"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:textColor="#0089BF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're doing this...

```
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    R.layout.activity_list,
                    R.id.task_title,
                    taskList);
```

... you should be passing in the layout you want to display a single item of the list in as the second parameter. Right now, you're inflating the layout you've posted the code for *for each list item*.

Your per-row layout can be anything, but the important thing is that it should have a TextView in it that has the `id` of `R.id.task_title` to match your constructor call, so that the ListView knows where to put the Strings you've supplied to it. For the simplest example, this could be your row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/task_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

But you can add a `ViewGroup` as the root element instead and build any layout you'd like, as long as the TextView you've given the `id` for exists.